# Regular Expression Pattern for Search in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I want to search a table which has file name(s) with a {Numerical Pattern String}.PDF.

Example: 1.PDF, 12.PDF, 123.PDF 1234.PDF etc.....

```
select * from web_pub_subfile where file_name like '[0-9]%[^a-z].pdf'
```

But above SQL Query is resulting even these kind of files

```
1801350 Ortho.pdf
699413.processing2.pdf
15-NOE-301.pdf
```

Could any one help me what I am missing here.

Comment: LIKE syntax is not regex: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is getting the substring before the file extension and checking if it is numeric. This solution only works well if there is only one `.` character in the file name.

```
select * from web_pub_subfile
where isnumeric(left(file_name,charindex('.',file_name)-1)) = 1
```

**Note:**

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($).

To handle file names with mutliple `.` characters and if there is always a `.filetype` extension, use

```
select * from web_pub_subfile
where isnumeric(left(file_name,len(file_name)-charindex('.',reverse(file_name)))) = 1
and charindex('.',file_name) > 0
```

[Sample demo](http://rextester.com/MRM78268)

As suggested by @Blorgbeard in the comments, to avoid the use of `isnumeric`, use

```
select * from web_pub_subfile
where left(file_name,len(file_name)-charindex('.',reverse(file_name))) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
and len(left(file_name,len(file_name)-charindex('.',reverse(file_name)))) > 0
```

Comment: @vkp My apologies, I did not see that.  removing comment

Comment: @vkp  I'm not being a putz (I'm a big fan), Try the second option with the table variable I provided below.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti .. thanks for the catch. i edited the query and added the demo based on your table variable setup.

Comment: Instead of `isnumeric`, you could use something like `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%` - in other words "doesn't contain a non-digit".

Comment: @Blorgbeard .. that is a good idea. But it returns filenames like `.pdf` , `.` etc. if they exist?

Comment: Yeah, you'd still need to split on `.` first - I'm just suggesting replacing the `isnumeric` call to avoid the problems noted in your quote block.

Comment: Oh, right - yeah, you'd need to check length > 0 as well.

Comment: @Blorgbeard .. i edited the answer with your suggestion as well. thanks.

Comment: it would be great if the downvoter can explain the reason behind doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you are trying to do using plain out of the box sql.  The [reason you are seeing those results](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx) is that the `%` character matches any character, any number of times.  It's not like `*` in a regex which matches the pervious character 0 or more times.

Your best option would probably be to create some CLR functions that implement regex functionality on the SQL Server side.  You can take a look [at this link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) to find a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version if 2012+, you could use Try_Convert()

```
select * from web_pub_subfile where Try_Convert(int,replace(file_name,'.pdf',''))>0



Declare @web_pub_subfile table (file_name varchar(100))
Insert Into @web_pub_subfile values
('1801350 Ortho.pdf'),
('699413.processing2.pdf'),
('15-NOE-301.pdf'),
('1.pdf'),
('1234.pdf')

select * from @web_pub_subfile where Try_Convert(int,replace(file_name,'.pdf',''))>0
```

Returns

```
file_name
1.pdf
1234.pdf
```